# The exact sequence splits iff $gcd(r,s)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, homological-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, exact-sequence

The following is an exercise:

> Let $r$ and $s$ be positive integers and let $n=rs$. Show that the exact sequence 
>   $$0 \to r \mathbb{Z}_n \stackrel{f}{\to}\mathbb{Z}_n \stackrel{g}{\to} s\mathbb{Z}_n \to 0$$
>   splits if and only if $gcd(r,s) = 1$. Here $f$ is the inclusion and $g(\overline{x}) = s \overline{x}$.

I already showed that $gcd(r,s) = 1$ implies the splitting of the sequence. I am having trouble with the converse.

If the sequence splits, then there exists an isomophism $\varphi: r\mathbb{Z}_n \oplus s\mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ satisfying

$$\varphi(r \overline{x},0) = r\overline{x}$$ and $$s\varphi(r\overline{x}, s\overline{y}) = s\overline{y}$$ for every $\overline{x}, \overline{y} \in \mathbb{Z}_n$. My aim is to prove the existence of a pair of integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that 
$$\alpha r + \beta s = 1.$$

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: look at $\phi^{-1}(\overline{1})$ to get coefficients for $r$ and $s$.